# How can I find the function $g(t)$ in the equation of geodesic by scalar product?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-dynamics

A parameterized curve $f(t):I\rightarrow M$ is a geodesic of M iff its acceleration is everywhere perpendicular to M, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\ddot{f}(t)=g(t)N({f}(t))
\end{equation}

Where $g(t):I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Taking the scalar product of both sides of this equation with
$N({f}(t))$ we find ...??

$$g(t)=...$$

How can I find the function  $g(t)$ where Find the value of the $g(t)$ and the offset by the equation leads

$f(t):I\rightarrow M$ is geodesic iff it satisfies
the differential equation

$$\ddot{f}(t)+\dot{N}({f}(t))N({f}(t))=0$$

I found this solution in one of the books but I did not understand how the derivation and the reasons[image]

the book here [Geometrical Dynamics of Complex Systems: A Unified Modelling Approach](https://books.google.iq/books?id=eMLgTV2ktlcC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=This%20vector%20equation%20represents%20the%20system%20of%20second%E2%80%93order%20component%20ODEs&source=bl&ots=w8fQbsHRwa&sig=7CIPLKkFjIXzf7MZvfOwSEr6MIE&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLtJ3G07PUAhUJfRoKHWAnA9MQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=This%20vector%20equation%20represents%20the%20system%20of%20second%E2%80%93order%20component%20ODEs&f=false)

Can you help by stating the reasons

Thank you very much anyway

Comment: @Emed kareem:  Is $N(t)$ a *unit* normal to $M$?

Comment: yes it is a unit normal vector–fields

Comment: yes it is a unit normal vector–fields

Comment: @Emed kareem:  also, what does $\dot N(f(t)) N(f(t))$ mean in your last equation?  What kind of "product" is it?

Comment: see new update ...Find the value of the $g(t)$ and the offset by the equation leads $ \ddot{f}(t)+\dot{N}({f}(t))N({f}(t))=0 $.... dot (scalar) product.....This vector equation represents the system of second–order component
ODEs

Comment: see new update ...Find the value of the $g(t)$ and the offset by the equation leads $ \ddot{f}(t)+\dot{N}({f}(t))N({f}(t))=0 $.... dot (scalar) product.....This vector equation represents the system of second–order component
ODEs

Comment: @Emed kareem:  still not getting it.  If $\dot N(f(t)) N(f(t))$ is a *scalar* product, and $f$ is a vector, how does that work?  Don't get me wrong, I find your stuff engaging and that's why I am asking so many questions!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60235/discussion-between-emad-kareem-and-robert-lewis).

Comment: @RobertLewis See the new update for more reasons